# Can the phrases "carbon fibre reinforced polymer composites" (CFRP) and "carbon fibre-epoxy composites" be used interchangeably?

Tags: aerospace-materials, composite-materials

Does the "polymer" in CFRP imply the use of an epoxy resin?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If you don't get a good response here you could also try [engineering.SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/); there doesn't seem to be anything in your question that's specific to aviation.

Comment: I believe that polymers other than epoxy resin are used but don't have time to check properly. So I'd say epoxy is a polymer but not all polymers are epoxy. I admit I'm not 100% on it though. Asking on Engineering is a good shout.

Answer (score 4):

No.
Epoxy resin is more specific than the terms polymer or plastic from CFRP. CFRP does also include carbon fibre composites with other duroplastic matrix materials (e.g. phenolic resin) or even thermoplastic matrices.